# flatten two audio tracks with ffmpeg

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg

I record video in OBS with two audio tracks, and I use this command to flatten it:

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -filter_complex \
  '[0:a:1]volume=1.0[l];[0:a:0][l]amerge=inputs=2[a]' -map '0:v:0' -map '[a]' \
  -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 3 -ac 2 "${file:r}"_flattened.mp4
```

But I think this outputs to a potentially weird format, because QuickTime Player.app doesn't play any audio with it, and when I import it into Final Cut Pro it doesn't recognise it as having audio.

However, IINA can play the file with audio correctly, and when I upload it to YouTube it has the correct audio.

How do I output to the audio tracks correctly so that when imported into FCP the file will actually have audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicktime and its consumer apps don't like MP3 audio in a MP4. Switch to the default AAC codec.

`-c:a libmp3lame` --> `-c:a aac`